# Decode ByteArray with spring 5 WebFlux framework

Tags: spring, kotlin, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I'm trying to use new Spring WebFlux framework with kotlin. And I can not find where I am wrong with this code (myService):

```
fun foo(): Flux<ByteArray> {
    val client = WebClient.create("http://byte-array-service")
    return client
            .get()
            .uri("/info")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .exchange()
            .flatMapMany {
                r -> r.bodyToFlux(ByteArray::class.java)
            }
}
```

This method returns Flux with 7893 bytes and I know there are not all bytes sent by byte-array-service. If I use old-style rest template all is ok

```
fun foo(): Flux<ByteArray> {
    val rt = RestTemplate()
    rt.messageConverters.add(
            ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter())
    val headers = HttpHeaders()
    headers.accept = listOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)

    val entity = HttpEntity<String>(headers)
    val r = rt.exchange("http://byte-array-service/info", HttpMethod.GET,entity, ByteArray::class.java)
    return Flux.just(r.body)
}
```

it returns all 274124 bytes sent from byte-array-service

here is my consumer

```
fun doReadFromByteArrayService(req: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {

    return Mono.from(myService
            .foo()
            .flatMap {
                accepted().body(fromObject(it.size))
            })
}
```

Comment: So in some other function where you're trying to consume data from that Flux<ByteArray> you can read only 7893 bytes yes?

Comment: Could you try using Spring's `DataBuffer` type instead? It's easy to extract byte arrays from it, and you can leverage interesting properties from it (like zero-copy and buffer pooling).

Comment: @Orest yes, you are correct

Comment: @BrianClozel the result is the same =( only 7893 bytes are available

Comment: @PavelVarchenko could you please also post consumer function?

Comment: @Orest, yes. Changed the question description

Comment: Could you show the `MyService.foo` method signature and add a `log()` operator before the flatMap, to see what elements are being published?

Comment: Either get as `Flux<DataBuffer>` like @BrianClozel said or `Mono<Resource>` (I've not tried this, but there seems to be a `ResourceDecoder`. Getting `InputStream` with `WebClient` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right, and you just need to deliver the flux forward, this should work. I tested it on my own environment and had no problems reading all the bytes.

To get bytes:

```
fun foo(): Flux<ByteArray> =
    WebClient.create("http://byte-array-service")
        .get()
        .uri("/info")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(ByteArray::class.java)
```

Return bytes with response:

```
fun doReadFromByteArrayService(req: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> =
        ServerResponse.ok().body(foo())
```